# Simple unity moving function doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have assigned a script to a simple ball and tried to attach this code:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
Vector2 speed;

void Start()
{
    rb2D = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    speed = new Vector2(1,0);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb2D.AddForce(speed);
}
```

And It doesn't work. May I know what I did wrong ? As it seems that addforce doesn't work. And the object with script attached has a rigidbody2d component

Comment: Do you have an error? Did you try to put breakpoint and see what value is `rv2D`?

Comment: Did you try other ForceMode. See [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: It look like your Vector2 is a little small... Add force of only x=1 is very small! Maybe your object is moving but you can't see it

Comment: @LudovicFeltz usually it updates in object properties and X isn't changing at all

Comment: You are right :/ Try with a greater value just in case and try a Vector3 if you scene is in 3D mode... Also try another **ForceMode**

Comment: But your code looks right otherwise